# Exporting data from query and updating table if already exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I find my query for checking attendance. but now I would like to create a new table from this query what i can achieve with this commands.
I am using PHPmyadmin, MySQL Workbench.

```
Create Table if not exists report as
select DATE_FORMAT(attendance.Date, '%d/%M/%Y') as 'Date',attendance.emp_id as 'Employee ID', employees.Name,
employees.company as Company, employees.department as Department,
MIN(time_format(attendance.DATE,"%H:%i:%s")) as 'Start Time',MAX(time_format(attendance.DATE,"%H:%i:%s")) as 'Finish Time',
timediff(MAX(attendance.Date),MIN(attendance.Date)) as 'Work Time' 
from attendance
join employees on attendance.emp_id = employees.emp_id
group by DATE_FORMAT(attendance.Date, '%d-%m-%Y'), attendance.emp_id;
```

How i can achieve that if the `report` table already exists it will update those data in the `report`
Thank you.

Comment: I think you should consider a view in you case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table already exists, you have to use insert query,

```
insert into report (column_names) -- Provide respective column names separated by comma
(select DATE_FORMAT(attendance.Date, '%d/%M/%Y') as 'Date',attendance.emp_id as 
'Employee ID', employees.Name,
employees.company as Company, employees.department as Department,
MIN(time_format(attendance.DATE,"%H:%i:%s")) as 'Start 
Time',MAX(time_format(attendance.DATE,"%H:%i:%s")) as 'Finish Time',
timediff(MAX(attendance.Date),MIN(attendance.Date)) as 'Work Time' 
from attendance
join employees on attendance.emp_id = employees.emp_id
group by DATE_FORMAT(attendance.Date, '%d-%m-%Y'), attendance.emp_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, just question, will this copy only records what was not in the 'report' table yet? or it will insert all those records, even those what was already in the table 'records' Thank you.

Comment: It will insert all the records. Id you don't want to insert existing records, filter it by joining the table using primary key or unique identifier